# Problema para abrir una ruta por defecto con openFileDialog

Tags: c#

Buen día.
Estoy intentando abrir un directorio en una ruta por defecto de la siguiente manera:

```
String directorio = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\..\\Pruebas";
 openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = directorio;
 openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

pero no me funciona, me manda directo a la raíz de C.
Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: La carpeta `Pruebas` tiene como padre el directorio actual? Si es así deberías establecer así la ruta. `String directorio = System. IO.Path.Combine( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Pruebas") ;`

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra no, lo que estoy intentando es ir al padre del directorio actual, luego ingresar a la carpeta pruebas para que openFileDialog abra siempre primero en esa ruta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo la solución te anexo mi solución prueba si te funciona:

```
String directorio = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\..\..\Pruebas"));
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = directorio;
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```